High CPU Utilisation during aws DynamoDb batch write
We have an AWS Batch Job, which runs on EC2 instance:
Instance Type: c6g.medium
vCpu: 1
Memory: 1 GB
The application is a nestjs based.
This batch job read file from S3, and write those data in our dynamoDb using DynamoDbDocument.batchWrite method. The chunk size is 20 in length only. There can be total of 20 chucks or 100 chunks. Size is way too small.
When we are doing the batch write operation, the CPU utilisation is reaching to 90%. Why is it going so high ? Other than increasing the vCpu, how can we reduce the load ?
Table is configured as follows:

1 Partition Key
No OF GSI: 2
Capacity: On-demand
Average Item Size: 688 Bytes

Edit: 12-June
After testing some more, we noticed the CPU utilisation is going higher when the number of record to write is more than chunk size. DynamoDb takes max of 25 records at a time. We are using only 20. If there are more than 20 transactions, then multiple batchWrite operations will be performed. My guess is since there are multiple batches, each batch will be waiting for the previous batch write to finish, and since this instance has only 1 vCpu, the waiting period is getting counted toward CPU utilisation
Edit: 14-June
We decided to switch the instance type from c6g.medium to c6g.large with 2 vCpu. This is what we found till now:



Number of transactions to insert
1vCpu CPU Utilisation (%)
2vCpu CPU Utilisation (%)




1000
90
50-60


100
80-90
50


50
76-80
1-2


35
76-80
1-2


20
1-2
1-2


10
1-2
1-2



Note: Each batch operation contains only 20 records at a time.

You first need to understand whats causing the load on the CPU, as I wouldn't think a BatchWrite would cause that. I would suggest you do some further CPU usage investigation.

This is after multiple tests only. We stripped the code that would interact with anything outside the application including db access / s3 access. Then tested each one of them at a time, and noticed this issue during batch write only.

And did you check which processes were hogging the CPU?

it is happening when we are writing to dynamoDb in batches

I get that. But which process is consuming the CPU?

can you share how we check that during batch write?
